# Predicting the next pseudorandom value

Tags: python, performance, homework, random, iteration

The archived material for the Stanford University course on cryptography at coursera.org includes a problem where you have to [predict the next output of a weak PRG](https://class.coursera.org/crypto-preview/quiz/attempt?quiz_id=18). It can be briefly restated as follows:

> $$\begin{align*}
>                    P =&\ 295075153 \\
>                  z_n =&\ x_n \oplus y_n,\qquad \textrm{where}\ 0 \le x_0, y_0 \lt P\ \textrm{(unknown random integers)} \\
>              x_{n+1} =& (2x_n + 5) \mod P \\
>              y_{n+1} =& (3y_n + 7) \mod P \\
> (z_0, z_1, ..., z_8) =& (210205973, 22795300, 58776750, \\
>                       &\ \ 121262470, 264731963, 140842553, \\
>                       &\ \ 242590528, 195244728, 86752752) \\
>                  z_9 =& ???
> \end{align*}$$

I wrote a small program in C to solve this by brute force, and it finds a solution in just over 2 seconds:

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#define P 295075153L

int main() {
  long seq[] = { 210205973, 22795300, 58776750, 121262470, 264731963,
                 140842553, 242590528, 195244728, 86752752 };
  long i, x, y, x0, y0;
  
  for (x0=0; x0<P; x0++) {   /* Try every value of x_0 */
    y0 = seq[0] ^ x0;        /* Calculate y_0 from x_0 */
    for (x=x0,y=y0,i=1; i<9; i++) {
      x = (2 * x + 5) % P;   /* Iterate PRG and check values */
      y = (3 * y + 7) % P;
      if ((x ^ y) != seq[i]) break;
    }
    if (i==9) {
      printf ("Solution found: x0=%ld, y0=%ld\n",x0, y0);
      for (x=x0,y=y0,i=1; i<10; i++) {
        x = (2 * x + 5) % P;
        y = (3 * y + 7) % P;
      }
      printf("Next value: %ld\n",x^y);
      return 0;
    }
  }
  puts("No solution found");
  return 0;
}
```

I also tried to solve this problem in Python, but ran into two problems:

- Although it does find the same solution, it takes about 3½ minutes to do so. This means it is about a hundred times slower than the C program. Surely this can't be right?
- I'm also not happy with the way I'm checking for a match with the sequence values. In the C code, `i` is incremented at the end of each `for()` loop iteration, so when `i==9` I can be sure that every value was matched successfully. But this incrementing happens somewhere else in Python, so instead I have to check for `i==8` and will report a successful match even if the last comparison fails. How can I do this properly?

```Python
from itertools import count

seq = [210205973,22795300,58776750,121262470,264731963,
       140842553,242590528,195244728,86752752]
P = 295075153L
for x0 in count():   # better than range(0,P), which is **extremely** slow
    if x0==P:
        break
    y0 = seq[0] ^ x0
    x, y = x0, y0
    for i in range(1,9):
        x = (2 * x + 5) % P
        y = (3 * y + 7) % P
        if (x ^ y) != seq[i]:
            break
    if i==8:        # will be true even if seq[8] not matched :-(
        break

if i==8:
    print "Solution found: x0=%d, y0=%d" % (x0,y0)
    x, y = x0, y0
    for i in range(1,10):
        x = (2 * x + 5) % P
        y = (3 * y + 7) % P
    print "Next value: %d" % (x ^ y)
else:
    print "No solution found"
```

Comment: A factor of 100 between Python and C is rather common. I recommend you take a look at Cython, capable of getting C speed while still writing Python.

Comment: "better than range(0,P), which is **extremely** slow" In python2 `range` *builds a list*, so if `P` is big it's going to use tons of memory. In python2 you should use `xrange` (in python3 the old `range` is done and `xrange` was renamed `range`).

Comment: BTW I believe the problem can be solved with just paper and pencil. There are a few theorems out there about equalities modulo a prime `P`, so I'm pretty sure we can do much better than brute-forcing. Once you find a better algorithm the difference in time probably will be much smaller for the simple fact that the solution will be found in a matter of instants in both programs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a refactor of mjolka's version:

```
def generate(x, y, P, seq):
    for i in seq:
        x = (2 * x + 5) % P
        y = (3 * y + 7) % P
        if x ^ y != i:
            return -1

    x = (2 * x + 5) % P
    y = (3 * y + 7) % P

    return x ^ y

def solve():
    seq0 = 210205973
    seq = [22795300,  58776750,  121262470, 264731963,
           140842553, 242590528, 195244728, 86752752]

    P = 295075153
    for x0 in range(0, P):
        y0 = seq0 ^ x0

        if generate(x0, y0, P, seq) != -1:
            print("Solution found: x0={}, y0={}".format(x0, y0))
            value = generate(x0, y0, P, seq)
            print("Next value: {}".format(value))
            return

    print("No solution found")

solve()
```

This solves your second problem by having a function "extract" the control flow, and use a sentinel as the return to signal failure to match.

I used `-1` as the "not found" return value because it's significantly faster than the cleaner alternative of returning `None` on PyPy.

Times:

```
$ time pypy p.py
Solution found: x0=89059908, y0=164204369
Next value: 86752752
pypy p.py  1.86s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 1.874 total

$ time pypy3 p.py
Solution found: x0=89059908, y0=164204369
Next value: 86752752
pypy3 p.py  2.00s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 2.012 total
```

This is actually slightly faster than mjolka's:

```
$ time pypy p.py 
Solution found: x0=89059908, y0=164204369
Next value: 231886864
pypy p.py  2.12s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 2.136 total
```

This was significantly slower than the C compiled with `-O3`:

```
$ gcc -O3 c.c -o c

$ time ./c        
Solution found: x0=89059908, y0=164204369
Next value: 231886864
./c  0.28s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.282 total
```

but if the value of `P` is instead decided at runtime, the speeds are very close:

```
$ time echo 295075153 | ./c
Solution found: x0=89059908, y0=164204369
Next value: 231886864
echo 295075153  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.001 total
./c  1.67s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 1.671 total
```

(1.67s vs 1.87s). I used C++ to get input, because I'm lazy:

```
  std::cin >> P;// = 295075153L;
```

If you accept an uglier form of looping, this is as fast, removes the duplication of `x = ...; y = ...` and doesn't split `seq`:

```
def generate(x, y, P, seq):
    for i in range(1, 10):
        x = (2 * x + 5) % P
        y = (3 * y + 7) % P

        if i == 9:
            return x ^ y

        if x ^ y != seq[i]:
            return -1

def solve():
    seq = [210205973, 22795300,  58776750,  121262470, 264731963,
           140842553, 242590528, 195244728, 86752752]

    P = 295075153
    for x0 in range(0, P):
        y0 = seq[0] ^ x0

        if generate(x0, y0, P, seq) != -1:
            print("Solution found: x0={}, y0={}".format(x0, y0))
            value = generate(x0, y0, P, seq)
            print("Next value: {}".format(value))
            return

    print("No solution found")

solve()
```

Times:

```
$ time pypy p.py
Solution found: x0=89059908, y0=164204369
Next value: 231886864
pypy p.py  1.89s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 1.905 total

$ time pypy3 p.py
Solution found: x0=89059908, y0=164204369
Next value: 231886864
pypy3 p.py  2.00s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 2.003 total
```

Comment: I don't like that you have to split seq and that you call x = (2 * x + 5) % P and the other twice.

Comment: @njzk2 I split `seq` because passing `seq[1:]` lots of times proved slow. I personally also find applying `x = ...; y = ...` simpler than the other techniques despite duplication, but I've added another option that avoids that anyway (see update). If you're willing to bear the small runtime cost, you could instead just make a function to do an iteration and call that.

Comment: you can test `z = x^y` before updating x and y, removing the need to slice seq. that makes one useless test, though.

Comment: @njzk2 Since almost all attempts succeed 0 times, adding one extra test like that actually costs far more than you'd expect. I think it also hurts unrolling. The code took about 3 times as long when I tried that.

Comment: good point. I may try with an iterator, then (to consume the first item as seq0 and loop on the rest)

Answer (score 6):

There are a few code issues that tools like flake will pick up on, but I'll just focus on performance.

First up, switching to `pypy` reduces the runtime on my machine from ~3 minutes to 16 seconds.

> ```
> ⚡ time pypy orig.py
> Solution found: x0=89059908, y0=164204369
> Next value: 231886864
> pypy orig.py  15.79s user 0.07s system 99% cpu 15.915 total
> ```

Removing the `L` gives us another drastic speedup:

> ```
> ⚡ diff orig.py orig2.py
> 5c5
> < P = 295075153L
> ---
> > P = 295075153
>
> ⚡ time pypy orig2.py
> Solution found: x0=89059908, y0=164204369
> Next value: 231886864
> pypy orig2.py  3.93s user 0.04s system 99% cpu 3.988 total
> ```

Changing the control flow gives us a smaller boost

```
def solve():
    seq = [210205973, 22795300, 58776750,
           121262470, 264731963, 140842553,
           242590528, 195244728, 86752752]
    P = 295075153
    for x0 in xrange(0, P):
        y0 = seq[0] ^ x0
        x, y = x0, y0
        for i in xrange(1, 9):
            x = (2 * x + 5) % P
            y = (3 * y + 7) % P
            if (x ^ y) != seq[i]:
                break
            if i == 8:
                print "Solution found: x0=%d, y0=%d" % (x0, y0)
                x, y = x0, y0
                for i in xrange(1, 10):
                    x = (2 * x + 5) % P
                    y = (3 * y + 7) % P
                print "Next value: %d" % (x ^ y)
                return
    print "No solution found"

solve()
```

> ```
> ⚡ time pypy orig3.py
> Solution found: x0=89059908, y0=164204369
> Next value: 231886864
> pypy solve.py  2.60s user 0.03s system 99% cpu 2.633 total
> ```

Which gets us very close to the C solution

> ```
> ⚡ time ./a.out
> Solution found: x0=89059908, y0=164204369
> Next value: 231886864
> ./a.out  2.36s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 2.369 total
> ```

---

Forgot to compile with optimisations, which puts the Python version ~6x slower than C:

> ```
> ⚡ time ./a.out
> Solution found: x0=89059908, y0=164204369
> Next value: 231886864
> ./a.out  0.44s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.448 total
> ```

Answer (score 6):

To address your question:

> In the C code, `i` is incremented at the end of each `for()` loop iteration, so when `i==9` I can be sure that every value was matched successfully. But this incrementing happens somewhere else in Python, so instead I have to check for `i==8` and will report a successful match even if the last comparison fails. How can I do this properly?

In Python a `for` loop can have an `else` clause that is executed when the loop ends normally -- not via `break`. In your case you could simply change `if i==8:` into `else:`. The `break` under `else:` will then break the outer loop.